# JNI Invoking Static methods. Is the class object necessary?

Tags: java, c++, static, java-native-interface

Started using JNI to invoke static java methods from C++. Specifically, after getting a jclass (using FindClass) and a jmethodID (using GetStaticMethodID), I proceeded to call the series of CallStatic*MethodA routines. Turns out that all of these routines take a jclass as first parameter. I started wondering why the class object is needed: since all information was provided in the GetStaticMethodID, the class object seems unnecessary for the JVM to get the job done. I then tried calling these routines while passing NULL for the first parameter, and the invocation succeeded.

My question: Is it safe to call these methods with a NULL class object?

The incentive is: If it is indeed legal, I will not have to cache the class object for subsequent calls to the static methods (while remembering to call NewGlobalRef....). Caching the jmethodID would be sufficient.

Comment: Dalvik [doesn't use the jclass parameter](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/vm/Jni.cpp) in `CallStatic##_jname##Method`, so it does indeed appear as if passing `NULL` would be ok. I can't say anything about other JVMs though.

Comment: The JNI Specification says it's necessary, so it's necessary. I wouldn't write code that depends on a quirk of a specific JVM.

Comment: It works only because your static method doesn't call other static methods from the same class, nor uses static class variables !

Answer (score 6):

No, it is **absolutely NOT safe** to call such static function with a null (or an invalid) class pointer.

Your practice may very well succed, for example if your static method doesn't refer to any other static class member.  However, if your static java method refers to any other static member, your JVM will need the valid class pointer.

**Example:**

Take this simple Java demo `MyTest.java`:

```
public class MyTest {
    public static void mymain() {
        System.out.println("Hello, World in java from mymain");
        System.out.println(magic_counter);   // this will cause a segfault if 
    }                                        // class pointer is null 
    private static int magic_counter=777; 
}
```

And call it with the following JNI C++ snippet

```
... // JVM already loaded and initialised

jclass cls2 = env->FindClass("MyTest");
if(cls2 == nullptr) {
    cerr << "ERROR: class not found !";
}
else {
    cout << "Class MyTest found" << endl; 
    jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls2, "mymain", "()V"); 
    if(mid == nullptr) 
        cerr << "ERROR: method void mymain() not found !" << endl; 
    else {
        env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls2, mid);
        cout << endl;
    }
 }
```

Calling `GetStaticMethodID(nullptr, "mymain", "()V");` would fail. Because when `mymain()` executes, it will try to get access to the static variable `magic_number`.  The JVM will then use the class pointer you have provided and assume it's a vaild pointer returned by a class loaded.  But as it is null, the system will segfault.

Comment: I tried your example, and there is no segfault. 
I am using Oracle jdk/jre 1.8.0.45 on linux for java, and g++ for compiling the c++. 
What JVM are you using and on what OS?
BTW, I must be missing something... I find it hard to understand, that once the native/JAVA boundries have been crossed and JAVA code is being executed , 
the JVM  - in run time - still needs to resort to the class object passed in the C++ side of the border for resolving nested static members/methods...

Comment: just to make sure....I am passing NULL to CallStaticVoidMethod(NULL, mid), not to GetStaticMethodID(cls2, "mymain", "()V")...

Comment: @user4212919 well, I've same java version, running in 64 bit mode, but on windows 8.1 with MSVC2013.  I could run this example with NULL instead of cls2 if and only if I commented out the printing of magic_number.

Comment: @user4212919 the thing is that there is a calling convention, and if you don't respect it you have risks that it doesn't work. By calling the Jave method over JNI, from C++, you take some responsibility that java would take if you'd call the same function from java.  So you have to make sure that the called function gets what it expects from its internals.

Answer (score 1):

**NO** you shouldn't do this, but its important to understand why you **can** in some cases use NULL for the class when calling a static method.... At least in some implementations.
I'm certainly no expert on java or the jni, but if you read the source code at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/master/runtime/jni/jni_internal.cc its pretty clear that the android jni does **not** reference the object parameter for the CallStatic* methods...

```
static jboolean CallStaticBooleanMethod(JNIEnv* env, jclass, jmethodID mid, ...)
```

The only problem is you are not guaranteed that behavior on all platforms, this is just the source from one possible implementation.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp15982 mentions that the method must come from clazz so its quite possible other implementations make a secondary check before the call is made, even though this is a performance trade off a release implementation of java would probably not make.

Its worth noting that a static method can only access static members and therefore this call should be safe, however the jclass object is not an instance of the class it is the class definition, which could easily be used for diagnostic information or something else unrelated to actually calling the method. Be safe and store the jclass object, its really no overhead to do so as its not an actual instance of the object.

Comment: *YES in some cases it is safe to use NULL for the class when calling a null static method.*  That's exactly like saying, "Yes, it's ok to put 16 bytes into a two-byte block of memory allocated with `malloc()`."  simply because on "some implementations" `malloc()` internally uses 16-byte minimum-sized blocks.  Just what do you think would happen should the Dalvik implementation you link to change to actually use that `jclass` parameter?  Do you really think it's OK to write code to an "It's ok now, who cares about the future" standard?

Comment: I'm not a fan of it, but the fact is that historically many programs have relied on quirks in the implementation.  These quirks can become so well known that vendors actually persist the behavior. I would go further and suggest that most programs contain some sort of reliance on undocumented behavior, probably unintentionally. Situations like this have even caused major software vendors to leave bugs/quirks in place, lest a swath of on the shelf software breaks down.

Comment: Also even the main sun java hotspot does not use the parameter see https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/hotspot/file/5ab7a67bc155/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp#l1111, where 'receiver' is not used, and all locations calling it pass NULL as its parameter.

Comment: Someone who deals with the documentation could probably easily change the parameter description to be 'this parameter is not used, its value is ignored" then everyone in the future would not have to worry about it any further.